# Weird black rectangles and other graphical anomalies when gaming

Tags: graphics-card, display, laptop-display, screen-tearing

I have an ASUS Strix Scar 3.

I have the following problem of this weird, black artifacting on my screen. Here are some examples:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKloP.jpg

another example here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Mpt.jpg

It happens way more when I’m moving and the camera is close to something, and usually is more common when emitting light particles. It mostly happens in WoW, but happens in other games too sometimes.

What I have just learned, is that when using an external monitor, this effect does not happen. So it has to do with my computer’s own monitor. My refresh rate is 240Hz and 3ms. Manually limiting the FPS does not fix anything. It does this at low and high FPS. Also, is there a name for what's happening here? Is it screen tearing? Artifacting? Changing to Direct X11 or DirectX12 does nothing. Should I just send my laptop back to get it replaced? That would be a huge drag.

Some logs (these were taken months ago. I've kept to date all video drivers but the problem still persists so I don't see why these logs aren't still relevant):

MSInfo: https://controlc.com/bb5cc262

DxDiag: https://pastebin.com/Ey1j1qqi

There is a similar post I made on a different account about this issue, but I forgot the login to that account and can no longer reply. Apologies.

Comment: Looks like tearing. Do you have v-sync on?

Comment: @spikey_richie Enabling and disabling v-sync doesn’t seem to change anything.

Comment: Is it better if you lower the res? Are you on the latest GPU drivers? Have you tried windowed mode rather than full screen?

Comment: You can [ask support to have your accounts merged](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @spikey_richie I am on the latest drivers. Lowering res doesn't help, and I've tried both windowed and full screen and neither work more or less better particularly.

Comment: nVidia `Fast Sync` on or off?

Comment: @spikey_richie I don't see an option for Fast Sync, if I am correct in where to look for it. I can not find it under "Manage 3D settings" in my nVidia control panel. The only available dropdown options under 'Vertical sync' in the control panel is 'Off' and 'On' and 'Use the 3D application setting'

Comment: "Users can enable Fast Sync globally or on a per-game basis through the NVIDIA Control Panel. Simply navigate to the Manage 3D settings section and enable Fast Sync through the Vertical sync drop down. Note: If SLI or 3D Stereo is enabled, Fast Sync option will not be available"

Comment: @spikey_richie I don't see any way to disable SLI or 3D Stereo. My NVIDIA control panel only has an option for 3D Settings.

Comment: @spikey_richie For what it's worth, I think my laptop has optimus, so it uses my intel graphics card for things that aren't games and my nVidia GPU for games. I think that's why I only have "Manage 3D Settings" in the NVIDIA Control Panel. So I don't really know how to enable fast sync.